# Hadoop command enables two different virtual machines?

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine

I have two virtual machines, how can I put arguments in Hadoop to choose which virtual machine I would like to run?
Say I have v1 and v2 in hadoop node. The command is hadoop jar -mapper .. -reducer .. -arg1 -arg2, which argument enables me to choose virtual machine.

Comment: What do you want to run?The Hadoop daemons or MR jobs?

Comment: @Tariq Hadoop MR jobs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such property that allows us to start a job only on some specific nodes. This is decided automatically by the framework based on the location of data you are going to process. Once you submit your job TT will start the maps on the nodes where data blocks are available. It's not like that TTs on all the nodes of your cluster are going to work for one particular job.

But the important thing here is, why would you do that?What advantage are you going to get if you do this?